# Android Studio .apk build ZipException Error

Tags: android, build, duplicates, apk

This issues is resolved.
I deleted all *.jar file and add below code.

This is edit my gradle code

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'

compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.6') {

    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'

}
```

---

---

---

---

all.

I have an error but I don't know how to fix it.
I need your kind help.

I'm not so used to StackOverflow site.

because I hope you to understand my mistakes on my post.

This is the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/MessageConstraintException.class

and my build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.daehwankim"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: you have multiple `com.google.android.gms:`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya How can i edit my code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need both of these ?

compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar')

i think both have MessageConstraintException class inside, but not sure. try to remove first library (if the second one is enough)

Comment: I remove firest library. but same error occured... :-(

Comment: the idea is to look inside the 3 http jar and look if 2 of them contains the class. try to remove 1 on them. also a good "clean project" could help

Comment: I resolved this issues.
I deleted all *.jar file and add Library.

this is edit my gradlecode

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'

    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.6') {

        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'

    }

//    compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar')
//    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
//    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')